# Why doesn't bit shift work for -1 in java?

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

I tried to do `-1 >> 1` in java, but the result printed was still `-1` At the beginning, I thought this is because of sign extending nature of arithmetic right shift. But through additional tests, I found that `-1 >> [0, 64]` is `-1`. Why is this happening?

Comment: It _is_ the sign extending nature of arithmetic right shift.  `-1` is `0xffffffff`; the leftmost bit is a `1`, so when you arithmetic right shift you get more 1 bits coming in, so it stays `0xffffffff`.

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi Not a dup of that question.  In that case the answer has to do with the fact the shift operator uses only the bottom 5 bits of the shift amount, so `1>>32` is the same as `1>>0`.  This question is about sign extension.  I'm sure it's a dup, just not of that question.

Answer (score 4):

This is because of sign extension. `-1` is represented by the bit sequence containing only 1s. Using the right shift with sign extension therefore always yields the sequence with all bits 1, i.e. `-1`, regardless of the second operand of the bitshift.

Comment: @KelvinZhang There is no sign bit. If the highest order bit is set, then this means `2^31` is subtracted from the (unsigned) number represented by the other bits. (2's- complement representation)